# Reading multiple lines in a .txt file and outputting an answer for each line

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have written a program that accepts input from a `.txt` file and outputs the sum. I have correctly gotten the sum of the numbers in one line. I need outputs for all the lines in the file.

The requirements for this are to include a semicolon to indicate end of line in the `.txt` file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs{"formula.txt"};
    int sum = 0;
    ifs >> sum;
    //int input = 0;
    {
        for (char a; ifs >> a;)
        {
            int num;
            ifs >> num;
            if(a == '+')
            {
                sum += num;
            }

            if(a == '-')
            {
                sum -= num; 
            }

            if( a== ';')
            {
                sum += num;
                sum -= num;
            } 
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: .txt file contains 
     15 ;
     10 + 3 + 0 + 25 ;
     5 + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9 + 10 - 11 ;

     Out Put Should be 
     15
     38
      4

     I got 247.

Comment: Please move your remark into the question editing it, and correct the indent in your code

Comment: What is the goal of `sum+= num; sum-= num;` ?

Comment: Adding the numbers

Comment: but you first add num and then subtract num right after.

Comment: If + sign add number

Comment: If - sign subtract

Comment: Sure, but what do you think will happen if you do them right after eachother?

Comment: @IntisarRatul after explaing why your program doesn't work I put a proposal of solution

Comment: Looks like you are working on the same homework assignment as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701820/).

Answer (score 1):

the line `cout << sum << endl;` is put *after* the *for*, so you write only *one* value at the end rather than the value each time ';' is reach

In

```
if( a== ';') 
{
  sum+= num;
  sum-= num;
}
```

*sum* in unchanged except in case of an overflow

must be something like

```
if( a== ';') 
{
   cout << sum << endl;
   sum = 0;
}
```

because the ';' marks the end of a formula.

Your loop cannot manage a form like `10 + 3 + 0 + 25`, because each turn of *for* you always manage an operator then a number

The input is `15;10 ...` and than cannot be managed, you read 15 and save it in *sum*, then you read ';' and assign *a* with, then you read 10 and assign *num* with so 10 is lost etc

---

A proposal :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  ifstream ifs("formula.txt");

  if (!ifs.is_open()) {
    cout << "cannot open formula.txt" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  int val;

  while (ifs >> val)
  {
    char op;

    while (ifs >> op)
    {
      if (op == ';')
      {
        cout << val << endl;
        break;
      }

      int num;

      if (! (ifs >> num)) {
        cout << "unexpected EOF" << endl;
        return -1;
      }

      if (op == '+')
      {
        val += num;
      }
      else if (op == '-')
      {
        val -= num; 
      }
      else {
        cout <<"invalid operator '" << op << '\'' << endl;
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat formula.txt 
15;10+3+0+25;5+6-7-8+9+10-11; 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
15
38
4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```