# evaluate multiple arithmetic expressions

Tags: c++

> Write a better version of the calculator, calc2.cpp, that can evaluate multiple arithmetic expressions. Let’s use the semicolon symbol that must be used at the end of each expression in the input.
>
> Assuming that the input file formulas.txt looks as follows:
>
> 15 ;
>
> 10 + 3 + 0 + 25 ;
>
> 5 + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9 + 10 - 11 ;
>
> When we run the program with that input, the output should evaluate all of the expressions and print them each on its own line:
>
> $ ./calc2 < formulas.txt
>
> 15
>
> 38
>
> 4

I'm stuck on setting up a loop for the char ";" that can do redo calculation for each line. Please help and Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char opr;         
    int  value;
    int sum=0;
    cin >> sum;  


    while (cin >> opr >> value)
    {
        switch (opr)
        {
            case '+': ++
                sum += value;
                break;
            case '-':
                sum -= value;
                break;
        }
    }

    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are working on the same homework assignment as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700113/).

Comment: it is but the assignment need to be done without <fstream>.

Comment: A stream is a stream as far as operator `>>` is concerned. It doesn't matter if you use `cin`, a file, a `stringstream`, a wrapper around a network socket, or whatever else comes your way. If it extends `std::istream`, it'll work. That said, it looks like your interpretation of the assignment is correct. If Intisar Ratul is a classmate, you should do them a favour and let them know they've misread the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an extra case to the `switch` to handle the `';'` and an extra `default` case should the file contain an illegal operator character to catch simple typos.

```
while (cin >> opr >> value)
{
    switch (opr)
    {
        case '+': 
            sum += value;
            break;
        case '-':
            sum -= value;
            break;
        case ';':
            cout<<sum<<endl;
            sum = value; // set first value of next equation as sum to set up for next 
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Invalid operation! Exiting program!";
            return -1;
    }
}
```

but watch out! The last entry in the file will get you! Given

> 15 ;
>
> 10 + 3 ;

as the input watch what happens

```
cin >> sum;
```

reads the 15.

```
while (cin >> opr >> value)
```

reads ; into `opr` and the 10 from the second equation into `value`

```
switch (opr)
```

runs

```
case ';'
```

which prints out `sum`, sets `sum` to 10 and loops back to

```
while (cin >> opr >> value)
```

which reads + into `opr` and the 3 into `value`

```
case '+'
```

runs and sets `sum` to 10 + 3  and loops back to

```
while (cin >> opr >> value)
```

which reads ; into `opr` and then fails because there is no `value` to be read. This would exit without printing anything.

The hack fix is

```
while (cin >> opr >> value)
{
    switch (opr)
    {
        case '+': 
            sum += value;
            break;
        case '-':
            sum -= value;
            break;
        case ';':
            cout<<sum<<endl;
            sum = value; // set first value of next equation as sum to set up for next 
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Invalid input! Exiting program!";
            return -1;
    }
}
cout<<sum<<endl;
```

to print out whatever is left in sum after the loop exits. If this is an introductory course, you may be able to stop here.

But...

You get the same effect from an input like

> 15 ;
>
> 10 + 3 cheeseburger

or

> 15 ;
>
> 10 + 3

And similar behaviour from

> 15 ;
>
> 10 + 3 + fnord + 25 ;
>
> 5 + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9 + 10 - 11 ;

which is clearly wrong. In the real world of programming you have to handle the cases where the the protocol is violated. The world is full of programs that didn't fully defend themselves from bad input and now their host computers are serving spam e-mails or worse. The instructor may be withholding a few marks to reward students who cover all of their bases.

Answer (score 1):

A proposal to solve the problems :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int val;

  while (cin >> val)
  {
    string op;

    while (cin >> op)
    {
      if (op == ";")
      {
        cout << val << endl;
        break;
      }

      int num;

      if (! (cin >> num)) {
        cout << "a number is expected after '" << op << '\'' << endl;
        return -1;
      }

      if (op == "+")
      {
        val += num;
      }
      else if (op == "-")
      {
        val -= num; 
      }
      else {
        cout <<"invalid operator '" << op << '\'' << endl;
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat formulas.txt 
15;
10 + 3 + 0 + 25;
5 + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9 + 10 - 11; 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out < formulas.txt 
15
38
4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do as you say......because you have to specify an end of the input. Otherwise compiler will be unable to determine the input and it will read indefinitely. So you have to specify somehow where is the end of input.